# is virtualenv used for runtime environement or development environment? Virtualenv vs Container

Tags: python, virtualenv

virtualenv is used to setup isolation environemnt. But is it used to setup runtime env only or development env that includes build and runtime enviroment?
Does it serve the same purpose as container?

Comment: You need to define your terms more clearly to permit a solid answer. What does a "build and runtime environment" include? Do C libraries exist within that definition? And how is whether something is a "runtime env" or "development env" a concrete question with a technical answer, as opposed to a question about how end-users *apply* the tool (which is by nature a matter of practice and opinion)?

Comment: thank you for your comment. When I said build env I mean like code editing/text edit and runtime is the implementation of code. Dev env is a combination of both. I am quite confused with Virtualenv and container in this sense. Your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: It's not typical to put your text editing tools inside a container, and it's *also* not typical for those tools to have dependencies that are provided by virtualenv. Can you be more clear about *exactly* what you mean by the word "runtime" above? Are you referring to the Python interpreter itself? The Python libraries it loads? The (generally-OS-vendor-provided) native-C libraries it links to?

Comment: Thanks Charles. Yes, I mean Python interpreter and python libraries.

Comment: A virtualenv versions Python libraries, but *not* a Python interpreter (it only links to an interpreter installed elsewhere in the host OS). A container controls all filesystem content accessible to the process -- not just the Python libraries, but also the Python interpreter, and the typically-OS-managed content such as the C standard library and similar.